# ssh error while starting namenode

Tags: linux, hadoop, ssh, bigdata

I have been trying to start the services in hadoop using the command

```
start-dfs.sh
```

it gives me the following results

[image]
why is this happening and what should be done?

Comment: "it gives me the following results"  What results?

Comment: please click "1" before the question.."why is this happening and what should be done?"

Comment: 1 is an image showing the error

Comment: check your `/etc/hosts` file vs. hadoop configureation (`*-site.xml` files) - are they properly configured and hostname matches in both configurations?